# Is avaliable to know JasperReports version only with the jrxml file?

Tags: jasper-reports

I just creating a new jrxml file with visual tool, but i don't know what version of *JasperReports* I needed, but I have some jrxml examples made with the correct version, if there anyway to know the version that created the reports? (inside a file or sth like that..)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Get JasperReports version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18406834/876298)

Comment: yeah..is the same question more or less,ty. so there is no way no know it?

Comment: For *jrxml* file - no. You can add comments manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short Answer: No.

Long Answer: You can almost infer version from the JRXML.

Sometimes the JasperReports JRXML schema will change based on new features etc.  Recently there was the introduction of a UUID attribute on many objects/elements.  This UUID attribute could not be understood by iReport versions earlier than 4.1.2.

So there can be small differences that you can use to 'hint' at different JasperReports versions, but not much.  Are you running creating the JasperReports for a software product?

You may want to peruse the supplied Jar files to get a clue as to which JasperReports version they are using, then match that with iReport?

Comment: ok that'a explication is enough to me. ty.muchas gracias compadre!